# PHP Remove File from Folder and Database

Tags: php, html, database, image, file

I am trying to delete image from folder and database using php unlink function and delete query. Here is my code,problem is i will not delete the image from folder. Please help.

```
 $filetmp=$_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"];
      $filename=$_FILES["images"]["name"];
      $filetype=$_FILES["images"]["type"];
      $filepath= "photo2/".$filename;
      move_uploaded_file( $filetmp,$filepath);
      $data=array($page_id,$filepath);
     $add=add_data_event($data);
      foreach ($errors as $value)
         {
              echo $value;
         }           
        if(isset($_GET['id']))
            {
                $id=$_GET['id'];
                delete_event1($id);
                unlink("photo2/".$filename);
               header('location:hotel2_galery_event.php?page_id=2');

            }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group has-info">
<label>Event Related images</label>
<input type="file" name="images"><br>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
<span>SUBMIT</span>
</button>
```

Comment: does your folder have permission to delete files?

Comment: you should see the error in the error log, I think @sandeepsure hits the point

Comment: folder permission issue.. as said by @sandeepsure

Comment: probably wrong path aswell..

Comment: Try with the full path to the image rather than the relative one shown

Comment: move uploaded file on top and delete file on bottom what do you mean with that..? is the same page you are using for uploading and deleting file..???

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this,

http://www.codingcage.com/2014/12/delete-uploaded-files-from-folder-in-php.html

Hope this helps.

Sohail.